# Step line pivot chart excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a line overlaid on some bars in a pivot chart in excel, but I want the line to be stepped instead of curved. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: When you right click and "change series chart type" what have you selected? Could you provide an example of what you have vs what you want?

Comment: So as chart type I selected line. This gets me pretty close to what I want. I have sloped lines between data points, but what I would like is to have a verticle lines between the data points and then have short horizontal likes at the data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything to do with charting in Excel, @Jon Peltier is *the* man but a line chart that looks as on the left below can be converted into a stepped chart as on the right without calculation quite simply by repeating the X-axis values (in order) and inserting duplicate values with an offset as shown:

[image: SU385252 example]

Though I admit I don't really know whether this is what you would like.

Comment: wow thanks for finding a year old problem and answering, that's awesome! I can't even remember what the problem was though, so I can't tell ya if your answer works or not. But it looks pretty great to me! Thanks again!

Comment: haha seems like a solid excuse to me

Answer (score 1):

Error bars can be quite useful, even if you do not know what they are fully for; in most cases, they can be used to show variations in data; but when used creatively, they can turn any line into a stepped line.

Here's a writeup of it:  [Step Charts in Microsoft Excel](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/StepChart.html)

Essentially, your adding error bars to a range of data, and then just hiding all but the error bars; turns out quite nicely, if you follow the instructions.

There is another method; however, that involves adding extra data to your chart; or, adding extra calculations to the chart, to 'simulate' data.

Comment: I tried the error bar method and did not have much success. Could you elaborate on the extra calculations method?